# road trip with my dog

Tags: road-trips, pets

I am going from NYC to San Antonio TX- about 28 hours- and have planned several stops. My dog loves to be in the car. I am wondering if it is better to go a short (ie 4 hr) day and then a long one (ie 8-9 hrs) or to balance them out. Some of the stops are good in the short days and the long ones have few places to stop. Any advice very welcome.

Comment: Have a look at [**Travels with Charley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travels_with_Charley) - may actually be useful and if not, you will be captivated anyway if you have not met it. 
A 10,000 mile US road trip by one man **and** a 10 year old French Poodle. When the 'one man' happens to be the awesome great [John Steinbeck ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Steinbeck)  'it's all on'.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**Travels with Charley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travels_with_Charley) - may actually be useful and if not, you will be captivated anyway if you have not met it.

A 10,000 mile US road trip by one man **and** a 10 year old French Poodle.
When the 'one man' happens to be the awesome great [John Steinbeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Steinbeck)   'it's all on'.

I started this more as a humorous comment, but Steinbeck probably has some useful things to say on the subject -  and 10,000 miles of experience.

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140053204) will, of course, sell you one.

[AbeBOOKs](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?an=steinbeck&sts=t&tn=travels+with+charley) will sell you 863. From $3.48 used - free shipping in US.

Answer (score 1):

I've traveled a lot with dogs, but since every dog is different you have to know how well his bladder holds.

Generally they adapt to whatever you do, 8 hours shouldn't be too crazy. 
You just need to stop every few hours and take a walk with the dog, but you have to stop anyway to pee and eat so this shouldn't be a problem.

It's a problem if you have to enter an estabilishment to eat and there's no place in the shade to park the car and you can't leave your windows open. 
So it's better to bring your own food or buy stuff and then eat outside with the dog if you're alone.

The worst that can happen is that your dog is agitated when you stop and just want to sleep, but usually traveling in a car is stimulating enough for dogs too if they can see outside.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the timings that works best for the driver.
You say your dog is alright with long days in a car. I guess the dog will be happy as long as you get a few long walks or good runs during your stops.